# Django joining 2 tables which has 2 join conditions

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 tables say A and B

```
class A(models.Model):
  A_val= models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)
  A_name= models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
  A_type= models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
  unique_together(A_val,A_name)

 class B(models.Model):
    A_val=models.ForeignKey(A)
    A_name=models.ForeignKey(A)
```

Now i want

```
select * from B,A where A.A_val=B.A_val and A.A_name=B.B_name and A_type="typename"
```

I did the following as told by miki725 to achieve this

```
B.objects.filter(A_name__A_type='type_name').select_related('A_name', 'A_val')
```

But this is equivalent to

```
select * from B,A where A.A_name=B.B_name and A_type="typename"
```

It ignores **A.A_val=B.A_val** . I want the join to be based on all 3 conditions. How can i do this

Comment: I have replied to your original question with an answer. Continue there instead of opening a new question for the same problem